# Can BFILE be used with JPA to share images between Oracle and Spring?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-mvc, jpa, eclipselink

I am developing a web application backed by a database that will include millions of images as its primary content. I am writing in Java with Spring MVC and am using JPA (EclipseLink) to connect to an Oracle 11g (11.2.0.1.0) database. The web server (running Tomcat) and the database server are different machines.

I currently have this code in my object model:

```
@Lob @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Column (name = "data_file")
private byte[] dataArray;
```

This results in a BLOB column in my table. Conveniently, I can view the images directly from the database using Oracle SQL developer.

The problem is that in order to display an image in the web app, I need to have an actual file, and on top of that, my understanding is that Spring requires this file to be in the web app directory, or otherwise at least in some other location that I've specifically configured it to be allowed to access. This means I need to create temporary copies of the images in order to display them to the user. I'd rather have the images live in only one location that is accessible to both the database and the web app, and if possible, I'd like to allow read access by other programs or by machine users.

I think the BFILE type was designed to allow external files and even remote files to be managed by the database. Can I use BFILE with JPA, and will it meet my needs? If so, how would I create a mapping to a BFILE column?

My goals are:

1. Images do not need to be copied to be displayed.
2. Files are managed as files (rather than String paths) in Oracle.
3. I can use JPA.
4. Files live in an ordinary disk location that allows read access.
5. I can view images in Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: late comment, but did you manage to find a hint?